# data.table version of split and repeat

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to convert some code to use `data.table`.  In this situation, I need to create a graph structure from columns in a data.frame/data.table where rows have information containing the id and depth in the tree.  My normal approach is a split/apply/combine, so I feel like it should be possible using `by` and some expression in `data.table` but I can't get it.

Here is an example,

```
## A data.table like this with ids and levels
dat <- data.table(level = rep(1:4, times=2^(0:3)), id = 1:15)

## my normal way, not using data table would involve a split and rep
levs <- split(dat$id, dat$level)
nodes <- unlist(mapply(function(a,b) rep(a, length.out=b), head(levs, -1L),
                       tail(lengths(levs), -1L)), use.names = FALSE)

## Desired result
res <- cbind(nodes, dat$id[-1L])

## To visualize
library(igraph)
plot(graph_from_edgelist(cbind(nodes, dat$id[-1L])), layout=layout.reingold.tilford,
     asp=0.6)
```

[image]

#### Edit

I think the problem I'm having is when I do a `by=level` I need information from two levels to get the proper repeat lenght.

Comment: If your tree always follows this simple structure, just make a tree with that structure (for which knowing the level is sufficient) and assign the IDs after the fact. If your structure can be more complicated, probably the info in `dat` is insufficient to pin it down...

Comment: To clarify `make_tree_edgelist = function(lev) cbind( rep(seq(2^(lev-1)-1), each=2), seq(2, 2^lev-1) )`

Comment: Still seems like a mathematical problem in which your `dat` plays (almost) no role, only the max level and the number of branches important. I could, for example, rearrange all elements on your third row and still be consistent with `dat`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way of getting your `nodes` column:

```
dat[, .N, by = .(level = level - 1)][
    dat, on = 'level', nomatch = 0][
    , .(nodes = rep(id, length.out = N[1])), by = level]
#    level nodes
# 1:     1     1
# 2:     1     1
# 3:     2     2
# 4:     2     3
# 5:     2     2
# 6:     2     3
# 7:     3     4
# 8:     3     5
# 9:     3     6
#10:     3     7
#11:     3     4
#12:     3     5
#13:     3     6
#14:     3     7
```